# Peewee throws KeyError when trying to add user defined operator

Tags: python, orm, flask, peewee, keyerror

I followed the short guide in the peewee docs on how to add user defined operators, but when I try to do it, it gives me a KeyError.

```
from peewee import *
from peewee import OP
from peewee import Expression

db = MySQLDatabase(app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'], host=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'], user=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'], passwd=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'])

OP['MOD'] = 'mod'

def mod(lhs, rhs):
    return Expression(lhs, OP.MOD, rhs)

MySQLDatabase.register_ops({OP.MOD: '%'})

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class User(Base):
    user_id = PrimaryKeyField()
    first_name = CharField(max_length = 150)
    last_name = CharField(max_length = 150)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    query = User.select().where(mod(User.user_id, 2) == 0)
    return "Query: %r" % query
```

When I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
KeyError: 'mod'
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining your database before you are calling `register_ops()`. To fix the immediate bug you can move your `db = MySQL...` below the call to `register_ops()`.

This does seem a little like a bug in peewee, though, so I've opened a github issue: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/599

---

Edit: I decided to after all not change the behavior. The solution I proposed should work, though -- register ops first, instantiate second. You can also specify custom ops when instantiating the database:

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Database

Example

```
OP['MOD'] = 'mod'

def mod(lhs, rhs):
    return Expression(lhs, OP.MOD, rhs)

db = MySQLDatabase(
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'], 
    host=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'], 
    user=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'], 
    passwd=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
    ops={OP.MOD: '%'})
```

Comment: im getting a KeyError: 'A@>' when trying to use psql array column type. Do i need to register_ops for it somehow?

Comment: No, but make sure your database is `PostgresqlExtDatabase` and not just plain old `PostgresqlDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

Before this

```
def mod(lhs, rhs):
    return Expression(lhs, OP.MOD, rhs)
```

You need to define this

```
OP['MOD'] = 'mod'
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to include that in my post, but I have defined OP['MOD'] = 'mod'. Edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
OP['MOD'] = 'mod'

def mod(lhs, rhs):
    return Expression(lhs, OP.MOD, rhs)

db = MySQLDatabase(
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'], 
    host=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'], 
    user=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'], 
    passwd=app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'])
```

Specifying the `ops` argument will lead to error, in fact, you don't have to do that.

The only thing you have to be careful is to import the function `mod` you defined to the module that you want to use it in.